# C++, std::async() и не статические методы

Tags: c++, классы, методы, асинхронность, адрес

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
Object object;
async(&Object::method, &object);
```

Я никак не могу понять, почему мы передаем адрес метода, а не имя метода.

Насколько я помню, имя функции, как и имя массива, является *синонимом* адреса. Почему для методов это не так?

Comment: Потому что это не свободная функция, а функция-член. И стандарт требует...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"имя функции, как и имя массива, является синонимом адреса"*

Да, функция часто автоматически преобразуется в свой адрес.

Но, как сказал Harry, `method` - это не обычная функция, а метод (нестатическая функция-член). С ними такого не происходит.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за помощь.